# android studio build error

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was so happy to see that there is a tutorial teaching you how to develop from Android Studio without a ROS environment.

```
h ttp://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment
```

Follow the spec, I changed the build.gradle in the new project to the following

```
> buildscript { 
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
>     } } apply plugin: 'android' repositories {
>     maven {
>         url 'h ttps://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/tree/master'
>     }
>     mavenCentral() } android {
>     compileSdkVersion 19
>     buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
>     defaultConfig {
>         minSdkVersion 7
>         targetSdkVersion 19
>     } } dependencies {
>     compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.+'
>     compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+'
>     compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.1.+'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
> }
```

Then there is an error when i tried to build it:

```
> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':CameraImuManager'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CameraImuManager:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not resolve org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.+.
        Required by:
            CameraImuManagerProject:CameraImuManager:unspecified
         > Could not resolve org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.+.
            > Could not parse POM h ttps://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/tree/master/org/ros/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/0.1.2/android_gingerbread_mr1-0.1.2.pom
               > 已经看到 doctype。
      > Could not resolve org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+.
        Required by:
            CameraImuManagerProject:CameraImuManager:unspecified
         > Could not resolve org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+.
            > Could not parse POM h ttps://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/tree/master/org/ros/android_core/android_honeycomb_mr2/0.1.2/android_honeycomb_mr2-0.1.2.pom
               > 已经看到 doctype。
      > Could not resolve org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.1.+.
        Required by:
            CameraImuManagerProject:CameraImuManager:unspecified
         > Could not resolve org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.1.+.
            > Could not parse POM h ttps://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/tree/master/org/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/0.1.6/rosjava-0.1.6.pom
               > 已经看到 doctype。
```

I use Android Studio on Ubuntu 12.04, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106376/android-studio-build-error/) by [Lunbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/9381/lunbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Lunbo,

try 'https://...' instead of 'h ttps://...'.

---

Originally posted by [ulceredge](https://answers.ros.org/users/9431/ulceredge/) with karma: 16 on 2013-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lunbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/9381/lunbo/) on 2013-12-03**:
Actually, I leave it like that on purpose. I cannot post URL since I am new to this community. Sorry for bringing confusing post.

**Comment by [Lunbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/9381/lunbo/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thanks! it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this it helprd for me just remember to change android{} accordingly

```
      buildscript {

     repositories {
    
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
  }
    }
 apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master'
}
mavenCentral()
 }

 android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

   defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
 }

  dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.+'
compile 'org.ros.android_core:android_honeycomb_mr2:0.1.+'
compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.1.+'
     }
```

---

Originally posted by [ShivrajDalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9516/shivrajdalu/) with karma: 1 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1